# Force the use of landscape resources for a custom VIEW with device in portrait orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, responsive-design, android-custom-view, android-resources

I am building a library of reusable components. These components are all custom `View`s (not `Fragment` or `Activity`). I have different layout files for each of these components to work best in portrait (view height > view width) and landscape (view width > view height). This works great when one of the components takes up the whole screen.

However, sometimes I will build an app that has several of these components on screen at the same time, for example:

[image: multiple components]

In this case, even thought the device is in landscape orientation, since the custom `View`s are each taller than they are wide, they should be using the portrait resources (layouts, dimensions, etc.).

I have a similar situation in portrait orientation:

[image: multiple components port]

Here it is clear that each `View` is wider than it is tall, so the `View` should be using the landscape resources instead of the portrait ones.

Even though this is basically a simple example of "responsive design", I have not found any easy/reasonable way to deal with this issue and am looking for clever solutions. Things to note before you write an answer/comment:

- These components are `View`s, they must remain `View`s. The are not `Fragment` or `Activity`.
- I do not intend to change the size of the `View` once it is placed on-screen. The `View` does not need true "responsive design" capabilities (ie: it must not resize dynamically or anything like that).
- I have read [this discussion about using window size classes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/large-screens/migrate-to-responsive-layouts) and it does not help me because that is only relevant to the window hosting the App itself. In my case, I need a solution **per `View`**.
- I do not want to force the device into either portrait or landscape mode. The user can switch between portrait and landscape mode and each `View` will be recreated, but it must use the appropriate resources based on the size of the `View`.

Any brilliant ideas?

Comment: "it does not help me because that is only relevant to the window hosting the App itself." - this is also true for resources, where the entire resource set that is loaded is also based on the configuration of the whole activity.

Comment: `val resourceId = if (viewWidth > viewHeight) R.layout.landscape_thingy else R.layout.portrait_thingy` seems like what you need. You would need to inflate that after the size has already been determined, so you can make your layout choice. You might be able to create a modified version of `ViewStub` that works along those lines.

Comment: Thanks @CommonsWare, I tried something like this but had lots of problems. Mostly because I'm building reusable components and the user of the components wants to access methods on the component inside his `onCreate()`. The size of the `View` isn't determined yet when the `View`s constructor is called, so I would have to delay the initialization of the `View` until the layout is finished and this causes an avalanche of issues for the user of the component. The other issue is that I need to have 2 layouts with different names (one for portrait and one for landscape) which I wanted to avoid.

Comment: "The other issue is that I need to have 2 layouts with different names (one for portrait and one for landscape) which I wanted to avoid" -- that's unavoidable, if you were expecting the resource system to handle it for you. The only other option I see is for you to have at most one layout, and have that layout plus Java/Kotlin code handle reconfiguring as needed for your two "orientations" (really, two aspect ratios).

Comment: yes, @CommonsWare, I know that I would need 2 layout files, but now I have 2 layout files with same name in different resource directories (layout-land, layout-port) and the Android resource system takes care of choosing the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy out-of-the-box way to achieve what you want with only the Android system API or supporting methods. I've looked for it a lot, and there are hacky ways I wouldn't recommend. I will give the only clean solution I found.

I've worked with similar views, and the general approach should be like this - create a custom view parameter that users of your library can use either in XML or directly in the code(or custom modifier if you intend to support composable) called orientation(aspectRatio/axis/etc.) with default to either landscape or portrait and based on that let your view to use relevant resources.

And move those resources from the landscape folder - for the android system not to misuse them - let your library users decide and control the UI for themselves.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping for something better than this. Basically what you've described is the solution I've already got (I didn't want to talk about this until AFTER the bounty expired). I've built a helper class to provide some infrastructure to support this (as I have many `View`s that need this) and I will provide my own answer detailing this approach soon.